# jQuery Object Serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

If I've for example an object like:

```
{start: 1, end: 2, someString="someStringValue"}
```

Is there any simple way to serialize it into a string of data? Example:

```
start=1&end=2&someString=someStringValue
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`param()` function](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.param#obj):

```
var str = jQuery.param({start: 1, end: 2, someString: "someStringValue"});
```